# Grails cron job executing multiple times in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz plugin for cron scheduling in my grails project.My application needed to poll third party API on regular intervals to get the status of an ongoing run and persist it for further analysis.The job is set to execute once in every 5 minutes using the following code:

```
class MyJob {

    def concurrent = false

    static triggers = {
        simple name:'MyJobTrigger', repeatInterval: 300000l //executes job in every 5 mins 
    }

    def execute() {
        log.info "Execute MyJob"

        //Get the list of objects which are running currently
        List runningObjects = someService.findAll(progress:1)

        runningObjects?.each{ 
                //Trigger third party api to check if run is complete
               String statusString = someService.getStatusOfRunningPhase()

                if(statusString.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    log.info "in success"

                    //update run status in db
                    someService.updateStatus()

                   //Do further processing

                } else if("inprogress".equalsIgnoreCase(statusString)){

                    log.info "in progress : do nothing"

                } else {
                    log.info "run failed"

                    //update fail status in db
                    someService.updateStatus()
                } 

        }
    }
}
```

When i run the project on my local machine using the built in Jetty, everything works fine. 
However when i deploy the same war on tomcat on dev machine, the job status is getting updated in db automatically . I don't see logs of these multiple executions

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a particular setting that needs to be set in Tomcat ?

Below is contents of QuartzConfig file :

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = true
    jdbcStore = false
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true
    exposeSchedulerInRepository = false

    props {
        scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
    }
}

environments {
    test {
        quartz {
             autoStartup = false
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: When you say "same war" do you literally mean the very same war file? Meaning, that you're running the app with the same configuration (ex. dev, test, or prod) on both Jetty and Tomcat. For example, `grails run-app` and `grails war` followed by deploying the war file yield different configurations (dev for the former and prod for the latter).

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa 
My bad. i should have specified correctly. i did run-app in local and deployed war file generated by grails war command on tomcat on ec2 machine.

Comment: Ok. Then i may help to post your quartz config.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa
I've posted QuartzConfig file. Please check

Comment: Hmm... can you explain what you mean by *the job status is getting updated in db automatically*? I wonder if the reason you're not seeing *in success* in your log is because info logging is disabled in the prod environment. You can confirm this in `Config.groovy`.

Comment: Please post what do you mean by "updated automatically", whatis the expected vs. what is it that you get?